# Hibernate Criteria / Query on object properties

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a class `AppUser`;

```
class AppUser {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   //-- getters and setters
}
```

I also have another class `Student`;

```
class Student {
   private AppUser appUser;
   private Date dateOfBirth;
   //-- getters and setters
}
```

How would i search for Student `John Doe`, firstName John, lastName Doe?

Had it been the date of birth property, i would create a `Criteria` and add an equality  Restriction (`Restristions.eq`) on the date. How would i do it for lastName and firstName in the AppUser object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Query:

```
Query q = session.createQuery(
    "SELECT s from Student s WHERE s.appUser.firstName=:firstName AND s.appUser.lastName=:lastName");
q.setParameter("firstName", "John");
q.setParameter("lastName", "Doe");
```

For using Criteria, check [this thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=948576&highlight=subproperty)

Also take a look at [this page from hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is it possible to achieve this without a `Query`, rather using `Criteria` and `Restriction`?

Comment: i have tried `appUser.firstName` but i get an error, unknown property

Comment: I updated my answer pointing it to the hibernate forums where a similar question was asked.

Answer (score 11):

You might need to add an alias...something like:

```
List students = session.createCriteria(Student.class).createAlias("appUser", "user").add(Restrictions.eq("user.firstName", firstName)).list();
```

Without an alias:

```
List students = session.createCriteria(Student.class).add(Restrictions.eq("appUser.firstName", firstName)).list();
```

Comment: The first one works for me, and I think it more directly answers the question because it uses Criteria.